# FreeRadius 3.0.8 installation error of rlm_perl

Tags: perl, voip, perl-module, freeradius

I have installed freeradius 3.0.8 and I want to integrate or connect it with perl and for that I enter perl in /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-available/perl and /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-available/default is also edited as per instructions on http://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_perl.

After entering `radiusd -Xxx`, I got the following error:

> -Wed Jun  3 18:43:10 2015 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[477]: Failed to find "Perl" as a module or policy.
>
> -Wed Jun  3 18:43:10 2015 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[477]: Please verify that the configuration exists in /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/Perl.
>
> -Wed Jun  3 18:43:10 2015 : Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[447]: Errors parsing authenticate section.

However, I also created symbolic link and the error pasted above is after creating symbolic link.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 'perl' not 'Perl' (you have the capitalisation wrong).

Comment: this is not the issue i already have perl in small but i also try it with capital one. Actually i don't have the rlm_perl.so file. I don't know how to install the .so file. please help me in this.

Comment: You need libperl.so, the perl binary EXTERN.h and perl.h else the build system will not build rlm_perl. Check you have the perl libraries and development headers installed.

Comment: what perl libraries i have to check?
I have already installed dev package for perl

Comment: @Faisal did you get solution for this issue?